# Do adjectives typically reflect the meaning of corresponding nouns?

Tags: adjectives

Is this a hard/fast rule, or are there exceptions?

As he had done during oral argument in January, the Chief Justice used his opinion to discuss how words and their derivatives can mean very different things, or very similar things, and so need to be read in context. 'Corny,' for example, has little to do with 'corn,' the opinion suggested

Comment: Think this question may be a bit vague. What do you mean by "reflect the meaning"? If I say "the overweight policeman", is your idea that "overweight" intrinsically represents part of the meaning of "policeman"? Perhaps you could give an example of what led you to this question?

Comment: I guess he is referring to words that are both adjectives and nouns (e.g., _yellow_), or to words like coward-cowardly.

Comment: Another vote for "too vague." Question requires clarification.

Comment: @ArthurRex: You know, if you just took a few moments to be more specific, include some examples, and make it clear what exactly you are talking about, this could perhaps be a very interesting question.

Comment: I was about to vote close, but I wanted to give the OP a chance to clarify his question, as requested in the comments above. It is beyond me why he should choose not to do so.

Comment: I think the OP was asking if it is common for adjectives that derive from nouns to have a different meaning than that noun.  I.e. 'corn' vs. 'corny', 'horn' vs. 'horny', etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule, adjectives are likely to reflect the meaning of the corresponding noun if they're derived via a derivational suffix (*-al*, *-ial*, *-ous*, *-ful*, *-worthy* etc) that is still productive. And vice versa if the noun is derived using a productive suffix (*-ness*).

If the noun isn't actually derived from the related adjective, or derived in a way that isn't very productive, there's probably more chance of one of the words taking on a figurative meaning without the other necessarily following suit. In the case of *yellow*, I think you could consider that the adjective essentially "came first" and isn't derived from the noun as such; notice that *yellowness*, derived productively from *yellow*, can have the related figurative meaning of "cowardliness".

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, adjectives do not reflect the meaning of the nouns from which they derive. For example, *yellow* as adjective means also *cowardly*, but *yellow* as noun does not mean *coward*; *yellow* as adjective has also the archaic meaning of "showing jealousy or suspicion", while *yellow* as noun doesn't mean "who shows jealousy or suspicion".

Comment: In this case, the adjective 'yellow' is a shortened version of 'yellow-bellied [sap sucker, marmot, waxbill, warbler, robin...](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special%3ASearch&search=yellow+bellied&button=)', so the adjective does originally have the same meaning as the noun from which it derives.